# Problems with Adding Breaks to User Input Data

Tags: php, html, newline, break, line-breaks

I am making a `textarea`, the value of which should be inserted into a database but the user input can contain new lines and the output should also contain new lines.

I use `nl2br($message)` to accomplish that but if the user inputs something like:

```
<ul>
<li>hi</li>
<li>nice to meet you</li>
<li>bye</li>
</ul>
```

it gives way too many spaces between each text because the `<li>` tag itself also contains some kind of break, so that means 2 breaks.

**My question is:** how can I avoid this, or which other function could I use to save the breaks of my user input?

Comment: Are you sure you want others to be able to enter HTML into your database and not escape it when outputting?

Comment: yes i would like them to be able to format their text (like b and i) and i also want them to be able to use lists. ofcourse i removed the ability of some tags with `strip_tags()`.

Comment: Then why not use one of the lightweight markup languages such as Markdown?

Comment: i can't download anything to use for the php codes

Comment: Have a look here: http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/

Answer (score 0):

if you are using textarea, it's better not to allow html tags to insert.. use php strip_tags() function for removing the html tags before inserting to database..